# Show file field as thumbnail if file is an image?

Tags: entities

I've added a field to comments to allow users to upload files. I want users to be able to upload different types of files, but if it's an image then show a thumbnail. Can this be done while just using 1 field?

Comment: Thanks for reputation, this module will be helpful. please make your module available for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is writing your own display formatter for file fields. have a look at [field_example](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/field_example!field_example.module/group/field_example/7) module to see where you should start:

first define your display formatter using [hook_field_formatter_info](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_info/7), here with `field types` you can specify that this display formatter is for file fields.

then all you need is implementing [hook_field_formatter_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_view/7), here you should output different `$element` based on `$item` extension.

after developing this tiny module, go to `comment display setting` in your content type page and select your new display formatter to rendering that field.

From field example module:

1. [field_example_field_formatter_info](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/field_example!field_example.module/function/field_example_field_formatter_info/7)
2. [field_example_field_formatter_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/field_example!field_example.module/function/field_example_field_formatter_view/7)

Answer (score 2):

I could also create a template for the comment, or the field and then insert an "if".

Comment: This seems workable, easier for me with my limited programming skills than Alexandru Savin's solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best candidate for this job is `hook_field_prepare_view()`. You can alter field's values just before they get to be displayed. Take a look at the docs [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_prepare_view/7).

Comment: Im surprised theres no module solution, this seems like a requirement a few people would want. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found y'all's answers really helpful, but for my purposes, the [custom_formatters](http://drupal.org/project/custom_formatters) module seemed to work really well.

Comment: How do you use it? It says you can define custom formatters without writing code, but when I went to look at the examples documentation page, it shows only code: https://www.drupal.org/node/2532498